# Доступ к WebSocket с определённых доменов

Tags: websocket, socket.io

Используется NodeJS + socket.io, всё отлично работает.
Но есть момент: если взять наш скрипт и разместить на любом другом сайте - то можно без каких-либо проблем подключиться к этому сокету. Безусловно - ничего особо страшного от этого не произойдёт, т.к. при передаче "не публичных" сообщений мы их обязательно шифруем и разбираем по определённому алгоритму, потому смысла пытаться "вытащить" что-либо - нет.
Тем не менее есть необходимость дать доступ к сокету только с определённых доменов.
И в этом и заключается вопрос: как это сделать?

При подключении к сокету каждый клиент записывается в массив, в котором хранится его IP и, если мне не изменяет память, домен, с которого он подключился. Как вариант - при подключении можно сравнивать домен с заранее подготовленным массивом доменов и отключать всех, кто подключается с посторонних доменов.
Правда каким образом я получал доступ к этому массиву уже и не помню.
Может ещё есть варианты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это нормально, и вы делаете правильно. Вариантов контролировать подключение по ws/wss существет несколько, но отличаются только сложностью реализации.